# reactjs : map the name a only when true

Tags: reactjs

[![enter image description here][1]][1]i am tring to show the    `subModule.subModuleName` only if `subModule.completed == "true"`

```
{predefined.map((personData, index) => {
        return (
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style={styles.th}>{personData.mainModule}</th>
            </tr>
            {personData.sub_module.map((subModule) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <tr>
                    <td style={styles.td}>
                      {subModule.subModuleName && subModule.completed == "true"}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </thead>
        );
      })}
```

sub_module is an inner array so i want to show only when completed is true

Comment: You can use filter method before calling map.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz when i give like this all names is shown   <td style={styles.td}>
                      {subModule.subModuleName }
                    </td>

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i want only names that are complted value is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** Using `Array.filter(e => e.completed == "true")` before using `Array.map`.

```js
{predefined.map((personData, index) => {
        return (
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style={styles.th}>{personData.mainModule}</th>
            </tr>
            {personData.sub_module.filter(e => e.completed == "true").map((subModule) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <tr>
                    <td style={styles.td}>
                      {subModule.subModuleName}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </thead>
        );
      })}
```

And please notice about `e.completed == "true"` condition, maybe it should `e.completed == true`. I just guess so because I don't have your input array.

Comment: this is not working now no data is showing

Comment: @MeenuKs add your input array please.

Comment: i have added a image

Comment: @MeenuKs Did you remove `&& subModule.completed == "true"` ? And try to change the condition to `e.completed == true` or `e.completed === true` instead of `e.completed == "true"`

Answer (score 0):

While one way is to add a filter before mapping, you can alternatively conditionally return your render content, and return a <React.Fragment/> when the condition fails. so that would be

```
personData.sub_module.map((subModule) => {
              if(submodule.completed==="true"){
                return(<React.Fragment/>)
              else{
                return (
                  <>
                    <tr>
                      <td style={styles.td}>
                        {subModule.subModuleName && subModule.completed == "true"}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </>
                );
              }
            })}
```

This approach is more efficient compared to the filter approach because you iterate over personData.sub_module only once, where the filter approach involves two iterations(one during filter, and one during map).

Comment: {personData.mainModule} how will i render this

Comment: Same way you'd render it otherwise. Capture the topmost level map result in a variable, and use that in the render method of a class component, or return method of functional component.

```
let renderData = personData.submodule.map(....);
...
return(
...
{renderData}
...
);
```